# MYSQL password is just not working...Error 1045

Tags: mysql, bash, plesk, parallels

## The Scenario

I keep trying to log into my Plesk MySql database called **psa** using the following command:

```
mysql psa -uadmin -ppassword*!
```

( This command of course assumes my password is **password*!** ). But I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

So I used the following command to check if the password was correct..

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/admin --show-password
```

It showed the password that I have been using. So now I have confirmed that my password is correct, but for some reason it is just not accepting it.

I then decided to try to log in using the hashed password because maybe that would make a difference...

```
mysql psa -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

...and it actually worked.

---

## The problem

Unfortunately, I am trying to delegate access to someone else and I can't just give them a giant hash to use as a password.

Why would it let me log in using the hash but not the correctly specified password?

---

## Important info

My password actually does end in an exclamation point, and after further investigation, I realized this might cause some issues. So I also tried to wrap the command in single quotes like this:

```
mysql psa -uadmin '-ppassword*!'
```

But that gave me the same error as before.

Comment: Try `mysql psa -uadmin -p'password*!'`. Or you could create a new account for your other user (which is really a good idea anyway)

Comment: @Cfreak I tried that command but to no avail. Creating another account or two will likely be what I'll do later on (especially when I start delegating to multiple users), but I just can't move forward yet without figuring out why this is happening.

Comment: If the hashed password works then perhaps the mysql password got set to the literal hash. If that's the case you just need to reset the password. Mysql doesn't read that file, its passwords are stored in an internal database.

Comment: If you set the password to something strictly alphabetical does it work? Try and eliminate possibilities. The `*` and `!` characters do have special meaning in some shells.

Comment: @tadman Cfreak's suggestion about the password being stored as a literal hash might be accurate. Resetting the password to something alphabetical would be his solution as well as yours so there is really no way I can test if * or ! is causing an issue.

Comment: @Cfreak You may be right about that literal hash storage. Keep in mind I have access to the database if I use the shadow file. Is there a way I can query the database to see the stored password?

Comment: It's in the `mysql` schema but it will be hashed so you can't see it. Does your admin account have all root privileges? Or do you know the root password (to mysql, not necessarily the server itself). You can try a reset with mysqladmin -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` password 'yournewpassword'

Comment: This question seems off topic for SO and belongs on [dba.se]

Answer (score 1):

Just create separate MySQL user with proper permissions, like

```
CREATE USER 'admin2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'properPass';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'admin2'@'localhost';
```

if you need new admin.

Answer (score 0):

Plesk 10+ uses encrypted password for internal use.
This is called Ehanced Security Mode (more info @ http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/71227.htm# ).

The hash is actually the password used in the mysql.users table.

You cannot change this, as this would break Plesk.
You can also not revert Enhanced Security Mode.

The only option is to add another superuser yourself.
Although I generally advise against doing so.

The hash is the true password.
If you need to have remote access to your databases, you also need to update the Host for admin user.
But again, I can only advise against this as this does not meet Plesk logic.